# Как в jade инклюд передать вёрстку?

Tags: html, include, jade, pug

пути:

src/blocks/navigation/navigation.jade

src/pages/index.jade

```
mixin filter
    div some text
include ../blocks/navigation/navigation
```

В самом navigation имеем:

```
.navigation
    .container
        .navigation-row
            +filter
```

Однако, данная конструкция вываливается с ошибкой undefined. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Напишите полностью текст ошибки.

Comment: jade_mixins.filter is not a function

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос перед примерами кода, в частности "mixin filter..." название файла с относительным путем от корневой директории. Например, directory1/directory2/index.pug.

Comment: Добавил. Решил проблему, в принципе, вложив индентом контент после include. Не знал,что так можно. Но в проблеме текущей всё равно интересно разобраться

Comment: У меня с вашей структурой и разметкой прекрасно всё из Pug в HTML переводит с помощью pug-cli (Node.js). А вы проект недавно начали? Почему расширения *.jade, а не .pug? Они же переименовались давно. С помощью чего вы конвертацию делаете?

Comment: Я предполагаю в чем ошибка... Вы конвертацию как запускаете? `pug src` или `pug src/pages`? Или что-то подобное. **У вас видимо также затрагиваются блоки в blocks/, но конвертацию нужно делать только для файлов src/pages.** То есть что-то вроде `pug src/pages`, а не `pug src`.

Comment: Да, я компилирую блоки тоже, это нужно(для некоторых). От перехода на Pug отказался в какой-то момент, потому что были проблемы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63148/discussion-between-alexander-bragin-and-sinneren).

Comment: Да в принципе Вы указали на ошибку, я исключил блок из компиляции, именно для него это не особо нужно, спасибо. Можете оформить как ответ

Comment: оформил как ответ. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае в файле `navigation.jade` не хватает либо объявления `mixin filter`, либо его подключение из внешнего файла.

Например, структура может быть следующей.

**src/blocks/navigation/navigation.jade**

```
include ../../mixins/filter

.navigation
    .container
        .navigation-row
            +filter
```

**src/mixins/filter.jade**

```
mixin filter
    div some text
```

**src/pages/index.jade**

```
include ../blocks/navigation/navigation

.other-1
    .other-2
        Example text.
```

Тогда при конвертации в HTML всей директории `src` — будет конвертироваться всё, включая mixins.

Чтобы исключить из конвертации ненужные директории: нужно либо подумать над структурой, либо явно указывать что конвертировать и/или исключить.